# Collision detection using a collision array inside html5 canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I am trying to detect if a character and an object inside an image collide. I am using a function that can parse the image and creates a collision array and another function that can detect if there is a collision or not in a specific location. My problem is that the `isCollision` function is never executed that's my jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/UNWWq/1/

```
if (isCollision(character.x, character.y)) {
    alert("Collision");
}
```

Please help me to fix my problem.

Comment: There are errors in the console. Check that first.

Comment: fixed it please check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i found it :
You are loading a huge background image, and you draw part of it on a much smaller canvas.
You do visual collision detection using a binary view on the display canvas that you build in the process() function.
The issue comes when you want to test : to compute the pixel position of the player within the binary view, you are using y*width + x, but with the wrong width, that of the background image when it should be that of the view (cw).

```
 function isCollision(x, y) {
     return (buffer8[y * cw + x] === 1);
 }
```

.
move right and look in the console with this fiddle :
http://jsfiddle.net/gamealchemist/UNWWq/9/

Answer (score 1):

Add this in the top of your `init()` method and it should work:

```
FieldImg.crossOrigin = '';
```

As you are loading the image from a different origin CORS kicks in and you need to request cross-origin usage when using `getImageData()` (or `toDataURL()`).

**[See modified fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/UNWWq/1/)**.

Note: in you final code this is probably not gonna be necessary though as you probably want to include the images in the same domain as the page itself - in these cases you need to remove the cross-origin request unless your server is setup to handle this. Just something to have in mind for later if what worked suddenly don't...

Comment: this error occurred when i just post the code inside jsfiddle but my main problem isn't there my problem is the iscollision function is not executing can u tell me why